# Unique IDs for physical modules added to a circuit

Tags: rfid

We have different battery packs that can plugged into our circuit, we're wanting to identify exactly which battery pack has been plugged in, but, as ever, in a very low-cost way.

I'm thinking RFID tags, but using a wired connection instead of RF... I've found unique id chips from Maxim (http://www.digikey.com.au/product-detail/en/maxim-integrated/DS2411R-T-R/DS2411R-CT-ND/2045729) but the cost is 10's of cent, and I'm looking for a solution for that's <10cents. (I'm guessing this price difference between RFID and unique ID chips is partly to do with die size)

There's a micro that's monitoring the cell, which would be doing the comms with whatever is on the battery. We're looking for a solution that effectively (24bit+ 1,000,000+unique ids)

Ideas: Passives? Crystal? Read RFID tag directly without RF? Lower cost unique ID chip?

Has anyone looked at this before?

Many thanks!

Comment: Do you have just bare cells or is there some sort of management IC per battery?

Comment: You make it seem like RFID's are a good solution. Maybe the best you can do is check around (E-Bay, etc) for bulk sales of large quantities at a lower price. Be sure to get detailed specs before buying.

Comment: How many pins do you have to play with?

Comment: What would happen if a second battery was left lying in close proximity to your RFID reader? Go for wired solution. You have to plug in a battery anyway so plug in the data lines too.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams it's pretty much just bare cells, no intelligence in there at the moment.

Comment: @Sparky256 + transistor only reference RFID as they manage to get an id on some form of silcon for less than $0.01, was partly trying to work out why unique id chips were so much more expensive.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel, 5 pins at the moment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would think some cheap EEPROM memory could be what you're looking for.  You can get 2 kilobit (~1e77 unique options) memory modules for about $0.11 each, assuming quantities of 100+.  [Here](http://www.digikey.com/short/3pq4hm) is a quick link to Digikey (many other vendors exist).  This method requires a physical connection and some pins for communication, but it probably one of the cheapest.

Comment: I think my common sense let me down here, I was expecting 64bit of memory to be less than 2kb... the power of scale. Cheers!

Answer (score 4):

I agree with Alex's suggestion of using an EEPROM but I would get one with a unique serial number already burnt on it. Such as Microchip's 24AA02E48 (datasheet [Here](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/20002124F.pdf)). It has a 48-bit globally unique ID or there is a 64-bit option if needed. They are in the $0.20 price range.

Plus you have the EEPROM to store future additional data, like batt. charge cycles, etc.